# Splitting Filegroups on a single SSD LUN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index, ssd

I've got an 8vcpu Hyperconverged 2008R2 Standard SQL Server with many TBs of data split across 4 Spindle LUNS. 
Each database has its Filegroups split into 4 physical files.

I'm being given a 1TB SSD LUN (woo-hoo), my plan is to move all* non-clustered indexes to Index Filegroups on this LUN.

My question is: Should I split up the Filegroups into multiple files (even though it's the same LUN)?

I've read this article from 2011 by Paul Randal: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/benchmarking-multiple-data-files-on-ssds-plus-the-latest-fusion-io-driver/
It suggests the Sweet Spot as being the number of Cores. But that was 6 years ago and things change.

I'm with an MSP who don't allow visibility of the Host, so I've got no idea about the true Physical NUMA I'm working with.

Can someone please point me in the direction of some good advice, or share their own sage advice?

*I won't blindly move **all** indexes. There will be some thought into that.